# Rails ActiveRecord query where.not(field: [array]) is ignoring rows with nil strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a simple DB query that is checking if a particular field does *not* contain 3x strings:

```
scope :not_abc, -> {
    where.not(name: ['A', 'B', 'C'])
}
```

The field in question is just a string with no default value, from schema.rb:

```
t.string   "name",     limit: 255
```

The problem is that the query above only returns fields that are non-nil, for example:

Returned objects:

```
name = ""
OR
name = "<any string NOT A,B,C>"
```

Ignored objects:

```
name = nil
OR
name = "A" or "B" or "C"
```

Is there any way to build a rails query that searches with an array of strings but includes nil values in the results?

What *should* be returned:

```
name = nil
OR
name = ""
OR
name = "<any string NOT A,B,C>"
```

Comment: `where("name NOT IN (?) OR name = ?" ['A', 'B', 'C'], nil)` add this.

Comment: ... Or using arel instead of strings.

Comment: @Arup Rakshit: Unfortunately, that returned the same results as `where.not(name: ['A', 'B', 'C'])`

Comment: so you meant `OR name = ?` has no effect.

Comment: Right, it had no effect to include `OR name = ?`

Answer (score 2):

Got the same issue and found the [solution here](https://forum.upcase.com/t/why-does-where-not-on-string-columns-ignores-null-values/3167/2)

Here is your scope in a version that should work.

```
scope :not_abc, -> {
    where("name NOT IN (?) OR name IS NULL", ['A', 'B', 'C'])
}
```